# Powershell IIS ServerManager not working on one server

Tags: powershell, iis

We have a script that runs during deployment to add some custom headers to the IIS website. This script runs fine on most of our servers but not on one.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Web.Administration") | Out-Null
$iis = new-object Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager
$config = $iis.GetWebConfiguration('sitename.example.io')
$httpProtocolSection = $config.GetSection("system.webServer/httpProtocol")
```

On the broken machine, the last line `GetSection` errors with `Exception calling "GetSection" with "1" argument(s): "Filename: redirection.config Error: Cannot read configuration file"`

- It should be getting `web.config` not `redirection.config`
- The permissions on `web.config` and `redirection.config` are the same on working and non-working server
- When I run it a line at a time, if I display `$config` it displays this:

Non-working server:

```
RootSectionGroup
----------------
```

Working server:

```
RootSectionGroup
----------------
Microsoft.Web.Administration.SectionGroup
```

I don't know what else to try/check.

Comment: You will have to check if IIS Express is also installed on that problematic machine, as `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Web.Administration")` might resolve to the IIS Express assembly and won't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

@lex-li might be right, the server does have IIS Express installed because it is also used as a build server. I worked around it by using the IIS cmdlets instead of loading the .Net assembly.

The params like headername and headervalue are injected into the script.

```
$IISConfigSection = Get-IISConfigSection -SectionPath system.webServer/httpProtocol -CommitPath $websitename | Get-IISConfigCollection -CollectionName "customHeaders";
$Header = Get-IISConfigCollectionElement -ConfigCollection $IISConfigSection -ConfigAttribute @{ 'name' = $headername }

if(!$Header){
    New-IISConfigCollectionElement -ConfigCollection $IISConfigSection -ConfigAttribute @{"name"=$headername; "value"=$headervalue;};
}
else
{
    $Header.SetAttributeValue('value',$headervalue)
}

$IIS = Get-IISServerManager
$IIS.CommitChanges();
```